# Laravel eloquent advanced where clause: variables not defined | I use use()

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I have this code:

```
$from = $data->chat_from_user;
$to = $data->chat_to_user;
\Log::info($from); // 1
\Log::info($to);   // 2
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
        $query->where('from_user', $from)->where('to_user', $to);
    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('from_user', $to)->where('to_user', $from);
    })->orderBy('date_added', 'asc')->get();
```

I get an error: `Undefined variable: to`.

I have found many topics, but the fix is always to use `use()`. But it still tells me the variable is not defined.

For example this works perfectly:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('from_user', '1')->where('to_user', '2');
    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('from_user', '2')->where('to_user', '1');
    })->orderBy('date_added', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: The `use` needs to be present on each callback you pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two closures, you missed at one. Check `orWhere`

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
        $query->where('from_user', $from)->where('to_user', $to);
    })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($from, $to){ // <- here
        $query->where('from_user', $to)->where('to_user', $from);
    })->orderBy('date_added', 'asc')->get();
```